# How can I let my recyclerview auto add itself an item when there's no data or the connection failed?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recently I started coding my really first android project by using Android Studio 3.1.2.

Inside on one of my fragments, I have a recyclerview, in which I want to show data from a JSON API. For the items I created a custom layout which is intended to be used as a CardView.

I proceeded that far, that I receive my data, but my recyclerview remains empty. Also, if the json object is empty, or the API deosn't respond, the idea was to let the recyclerview automatically add an item, that tells the user that there's no data or the API was not available (would be cool, if I could use the same layout here, I created). This is how my code looks so far:

The raw structure of report_compact_card.xml (embedded in `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        ...>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/report_header_textview"
            ... />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/report_body_textview"
            ... />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/report_icon_imageview"
            ... />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My ReportCompactAdapter:

```
public class ReportCompactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportCompactAdapter.ReportCompactViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Report> reports;

    public ReportCompactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Report> reports) {
        this.context = context;
        this.reports = reports;
    }

    @Override
    public ReportCompactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.report_compact_card, parent, false);
        return new ReportCompactViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ReportCompactViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //this is where I want to set a "no data" card
        if (reports.isEmpty()) {
            holder.reportBodyTextView.setText("Keine Meldungen");
            holder.reportBodyTextView.setText(":)");
            holder.reportIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_report_ok_24dp);
        } else {
            //here I want to fill my cards with my json data
            Report currentReport = reports.get(position);

            String currentId = currentReport.getId();
            String currentTest = currentReport.getTest();
            String currentTOpen = currentReport.getTOpen();
            Employee currentEmployee = currentReport.getEmployee();

            holder.reportHeaderTextView.setText(currentTest);
            holder.reportBodyTextView.setText(currentId + " " + currentTOpen + " " + currentEmployee.getName());
            holder.reportIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_report_err_24dp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return reports.size();
    }

    public class ReportCompactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView reportHeaderTextView;
        public TextView reportBodyTextView;
        public ImageView reportIconImageView;

        //this is where I try to access my layout
        public ReportCompactViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            reportHeaderTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_header_textview);
            reportBodyTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_body_textview);
            reportIconImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_icon_imageview);
        }
    }

}
```

Additionally in may OverviewFragment, where I use my recyclerview i'm doing like so:

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Report> reports;
    private RecyclerView reportRecyclerView;
    private ReportCompactAdapter reportCompactAdapter;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
        reports = new ArrayList<Report>();

        //here I want to set up my recyclerview
        reportRecyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.report_recyclerview);
        reportRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        reportRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

        //I already set the adapter here to avoid the warning that no adapter is attached
        reportRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ReportCompactAdapter(this.getContext(), reports));

        //I use volley for Request stuff
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getContext());

        //this guy is intended to fetch my json data
        parseJSON();

        return fragmentView;
    }

    private void parseJSON() {
        JSONObjectRequest request = new JSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "myurl.com", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("reports");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject report = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        reports.add(new Report(json));
                    }
                    //here I set my adapter after parsing my data
                    reportCompactAdapter = new ReportCompactAdapter(OverviewFragment.this.getContext(), reports);
                    reportRecyclerView.setAdapter(reportCompactAdapter);
                } catch(JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Because of some reason I didn't even get my "no data" card into my recyclerview, neither my filled cards, although "myurl.com" is valid and doesn't throw any error. So my question is, where did I mis a step to successfully squeeze my cards into my recyclerview? Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need return atleast 1 item in getItemCount() like below

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return reports.size()==0?1:report.size();
    }
```

Comment: It works so far, that I got my "no data" card displayed, thanks mate! Seems I stil have to fix some things around my json parser ...